# how to let button has focus style outline when QDialog constructed

Tags: qt

I invoke button's setfocus function in QDialog's constructor, or setfocus after constructor, the button is actually focused because it can work when I press enter or space key, but it has no outline unless I press tab key. if I press tab key, the setfocus function could produce outline. So how could button has outline whitout press tab key?

Comment: Are you sure you can trigger the button by pressing <Space>? That should only work when the button has the focus whereas pressing <Enter> works even when the button does not have the focus, because <Enter> just triggers the default button.

Comment: you r right, the <ENTER> key works because it's default button. So I cancel the default property and then only <SPACE> key works.